# Continuity of $J: GL_c(E) \rightarrow GL_c(E): T \mapsto T^{-1}$

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces, continuity

I have a question about a proof in my analysis textbook.

They show that if $E$is a banach space, then $J: GL_c(E) \rightarrow GL_c(E): T \mapsto T^{-1}$ is continuous by first showing that it is continuous in $I$ (the identity). Then they argue as follows: Let $U \in GL_c(E)$, let $r = \lVert U^{-1}\rVert^{-1}$, and let $V \in B_r(U)$. First, they write $V^{-1} = (U^{-1}\circ V)^{-1} \circ U^{-1}$. And say that now we can use the continuity of $J$ in $I$ to say that $J$ is continuous in $U$.

I tried showing that $J$ is continuous in $U$ as follows.

$$\begin{align*}\lVert U^{-1} - V^{-1}\rVert  &= \lVert U^{-1} - (U^{-1}\circ V)^{-1} \circ U^{-1}\rVert\\ &= \lVert (I - (U^{-1} \circ V)^{-1}) \circ U^{-1}\rVert\\
            &\leq \lVert I - (U^{-1} \circ V)^{-1}\rVert\cdot\lVert U^{-1}\rVert\end{align*}$$

Well now I guess I have to use that I is continuous to get $||I - (U^{-1} \circ V)^{-1}||$ arbitrary small. But, I only have that $|| U - V || < r$. Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By continuity in $I$, we can find $\delta$ such that if $\lVert I-A\rVert\leq \delta$ then $\lVert I-A^{-1}\rVert\leq\varepsilon$. So we have so see when $\lVert I-U^{-1}(U+H)\rVert\leq \delta$, *i.e.* $\lVert I-U^{-1}H\rVert$. It happens if $\lVert H\rVert\leq \frac{\delta}{\lVert U^{-1}\rVert}=\delta r$.

Comment: should that be $\lVert I - A\rVert \leq \delta$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't miss anything, now I've edited.

Comment: Hm, I don't see how you go from $\lVert I - U^{-1}(U+H\rVert)$ to $\lVert I-U^{-1}H$, since $\lVert I - U^{-1}(U+H)\rVert = \lVert I - U^{-1}U + U^{-1}H\rVert = \lVert U^{-1}H\rVert$?

Comment: Oh I think I got it! If $\lVert H-U \rVert \leq \frac{\delta}{\lVert U^{-1}\rVert}$,then $\lVert U^{-1}H - I \rVert \leq \lVert U^{-1}\rVert \lVert H - U \rVert \leq \delta$. Hence we have $\lVert   I - (U^{-1}V)^{-1}\rVert \leq \varepsilon$, is this correct?

Comment: @DimitriSurinx Yes.

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I had some kind of brain freeze or something!